# Show convergence of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, elementary-set-theory, hausdorff-distance

Consider the following sets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A_n\equiv  \Big\{ x\in X:  d\big(p_n,  [\ell(x), u(x) ] \big)\leq \delta_n\Big\}\\
& A \equiv  \Big\{ x\in X:  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d\big(p_n,  [\ell(x), u(x)] \big)= 0\Big\}
\end{aligned}
$$
where:

- $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
- $(p_n)_n$ is a sequence of  numbers taking values in $[0,1]$.
- $\ell(\cdot)$ and $u(\cdot)$ are real  function taking values in $[0,1]$.
- $(\delta_n)_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers going to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. In particular, $\delta_n\equiv \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log(\frac{2}{\alpha})} $ with $\alpha\in (0,1)$.
- $d\left(a, E\right)\equiv \inf \left\{|a - y| : y \in E\right\}$.

---

Assume that $A$ is non-empty.

---

I would like to prove (or, disprove) that $d_H(A_n, A)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $d_H$ is the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

---

Comments: I know that the claim is wrong when $\delta_n\equiv 0$ for each $n$.  See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464230/show-convergence-result) for a counterexample.

More generally, I am trying to understand under which conditions the claim holds. The two sets seem so naturally "equivalent" as $n\rightarrow \infty$ that I am trying to exclude pathological cases where the claim does not hold.

Comment: The claim seem simply incorrect, those two sets are not really related, especially since there is no relation between $p_n$, $u$ and $\ell$. 


If you take $\ell(x)=0.25$ and $u(x)=0.75$ and $p_n = \frac {1+(-1)^n}{4} $ (i.e., $0$ for odd, and $1/2$ for even) You'll get that $A_n = X$ for even $n$ and $A_n$ is empty for add $n$, and $A$ is empty (the distance is either $0.25$ or $0$). Did I miss something?

Comment: $A$ is assumed non-empty. Also, I have tried to reformulate the definition of the two sets in a clearer way.

Comment: if you want A to be nonempty you can modify $u$ and $\ell$ such that for some $x$ you have $u(x)=0, \ell(x)=1$, thus $x\in A$. For other X's, the same holds..

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I guess, you are offering a counterexample of my claim. Please put it in an answer  and provide some details. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amit said in his comment, it seems like you need  to demand more, even if $A$ is non-empty.

For a simple example, take $\ell(x)=\max\{x-0.01,0\}$ and $u(x)=\min\{x+0.01,1\}$ with $X=[0,1]$.

Then $A_n= \{ x: \vert x-p_n\vert \leq \delta_n+0.01 \}$ if $0.1<\vert p_n \vert<0.9$.

If you take $p_n= \frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n \cdot 0.01$, then $A_{2n}=[\frac{1}{2}-\delta_n, \frac{1}{2}+0.02 +\delta_n]$ and $A_{2n+1}=[\frac{1}{2}-\delta_n-0.02, \frac{1}{2} +\delta_n]$.

If I am not mistaken, then $A=\{ \frac{1}{2} \}$, $A_{2n}\supseteq[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+0.02]$ and $A_{2n+1}\supseteq [\frac{1}{2}-0.02, \frac{1}{2}]$. Which means that $A_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence with respect to the Hausdorff metric.

So I think if $p_n$ does not converge and  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \ell(p_n) \neq \lim_{n\to \infty} u(p_n)$, you can always have this case.

To avoid pathologies, you should probably assume that $u$ and $\ell$ are continuous and maybe also that $p_n\to p_\infty \in [0,1]$. Without assuming these there are probably many other convoluted counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks. What is $p_{\infty}$?

Comment: @Star $p_\infty$ would be a limit of the $p_n$'s. By the way, this is not a proof, but I just think that these are the first natural pathologies to consider.

Comment: The continuity of $u$ and $\ell$ does not help, as you can see in this counterexample here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464230/show-convergence-result. Further, unfortunately, I cannot assume that $p_n$ converges.  Would some other features of the sets $A_n$ help here?

Comment: @Star Do you have guiding examples where the claim does hold? It seems right now that it might be that the claim would only hold for a much narrower set of conditions than you wrote.