Relation between two sets, one with limit inside, the other with limit outside
Consider these two sets:
$$
A\equiv \{x\in X: \forall \xi>0 \text{ }\exists N_{\xi, x} \text{ s.t. } \forall N\geq N_{\xi, x} \text{ } d(p_N, I(x))\leq \xi)\},
$$
$$
B\equiv \bigcap_{\xi>0} \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{K=N}^\infty \{x\in X: d(p_K, I(x))\leq \xi\},
$$
where

$A$ and $B$ are non-empty.
$(p_N)_N$   is a sequence of  reals taking values in $[0,1]$.
$I(x)$ is an interval in $(0,1)$.
$d\big(p_N,  I(x) \big):= \inf \big\{|p_N - y| : y \in I(x) \big\}$.


Question: Is $A=B$, $A\subseteq B$, $A\supseteq B$?

Some thoughts:

$A$ is equal to:
$$
A= \{x\in X: \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}d(p_N, I(x))=0)\},
$$
where I use the definition of limit.

$B$ is equal to:
$$
B=\bigcap_{\xi>0} \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))\leq \xi \}=   \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0 \}
$$
where the first equality comes from the definition of $\liminf$ applied to sets (see here) and the second equality comes from my understanding of some comments given to another questions of mine. However, from the comments below, it seems that this second equality is wrong (any clarification would be welcome here).


So, $A$ has the limit inside, while $B$ outside. Is there any obvious relation between $A$ and $B$, e.g., $B$ is a superset/subset of $A$?

$B=A\ne\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{K=N}^\infty {x\in X: d(p_K, I(x))= 0}$.

Related (from the same user): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4898969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880218.

Thanks, Anne. (1) Can you help me to show that $B=A$?

(2.a) is it correct to write that $$B\equiv \bigcap_{\xi>0}\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{K=N}^\infty {x\in X: d(p_K, I(x))\leq \xi}= \bigcap_{\xi>0} \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in X: d(p_K, I(x))\leq \xi}\quad ? $$ It is taken from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets

(2.b) in a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4898969/distance-between-two-sets-different-from-zero one of the users has suggested that $$\bigcap_{\xi>0}{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))\leq \xi}= {x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0}.$$ (See in the comments) (2.c) Hence, my claim comes from combining (2.a) and (2.b).

@AnneBauval My use of $\liminf$ in 2a comes from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107931/lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-sequence-of-sets  I don't understand what is wrong

(2.a) yes, (2.b) yes, (2.c) no.

I will limit myself to your question 1 and your thoughts about it. Maybe you should ask your question 2 later in a new post, more clearly and with some attempts.

$B=A$ by definition of (infinite) unions and intersections:
$$\begin{align}B&=\bigcap_{\xi>0}\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\{x\in X:\forall K\ge N, d(p_K, I(x))\le\xi\}\\&=\bigcap_{\xi>0}\{x\in X:\exists N\ge1\;\forall K\ge N\;d(p_K, I(x))\le\xi\}\\&=\{x\in X:\forall\xi>0\;\exists N\ge1\;\forall K\ge N\;d(p_K, I(x))\le\xi\}\\&=A.
\end{align}$$
$B=\bigcap_{\xi>0} \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))\leq \xi \}$ indeed, by definition of $\liminf$ of a sequence of sets.
This $\liminf$ cannot be pulled out. More precisely:

the following inclusion holds:
$$
B\supseteq\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0 \}
$$ because if $x\in\liminf_{N\rightarrow\infty}\{x\in X:d(p_N,I(x))=0\}$, i.e. if $\exists N\;\forall K\ge N\;d(p_K, I(x))=0$, then obviously $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}d(p_N, I(x))=0$, i.e. $x\in A$, or equivalently $x\in B$.
the reverse inclusion generally doesn't hold. For instance if $I(x)=(1/2,1/4)$ ($\forall x\in X$) and $p_n=\frac12-\frac1n$, then
$$
B=A=X\not\subseteq\varnothing=\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0 \}
$$




Thanks. Regarding the proof that $B$ is not a subset of $\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in : d(p_N, I(x))=0}$: your counterexample considers the case where $\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in : d(p_N, I(x))=0}=\emptyset$. Does the claim hold even if we assume $\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in : d(p_N, I(x))=0}\neq \emptyset$?

You will easily find an analogous counterexample with $\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in : d(p_N, I(x))=0}\neq \emptyset$.

You have shown that $B\supseteq \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0}$. Does this imply $d_H(B,  \liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} {x\in X: d(p_N, I(x))=0})=0$?

No. Use the counterexample you are supposed to have found since the previous comment.
